# Can you use the expression "à l’heure où" with the meaning of "tandis que" to contrast two opposing ideas?

Tags: expressions

> ***À l’heure où*** certains salariés étalent leur vie professionnelle sur les réseaux sociaux, d’autres ont l’interdiction de parler de leur job. Une culture de la discrétion qui pourrait entraver la liberté d’expression.

The pair of "certains" and "d’autres" made me realise that the expression "à l’heure où" might have the meaning of "tandis que" here, qualifying only the first half of the sentence.

But without those two words, I might have easily interpreted it as a synonym of "à l'époque où", "à l’heure qu’il est", or "de nos jours" and thought that the expression qualifies the entire sentence, just as a sentence adverb does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je ne sais pas ce qu'il en est dans les autres langues, mais en français, l'**idée** d'opposition découle toujours de l'idée de simultanéité temporelle, à cause du contraste rendu visible par la simultanéité.

Ainsi, la plupart des expressions telles que "tandis que", "alors que", mais aussi "au moment où", "à l'instant/heure où", "à la seconde/minute où", surtout quand on y ajoute "même" ("au moment-**même** où" et ainsi de suite) peuvent porter l'idée d'opposition qui découle simplement du contraste.

> Au moment-même où des enfants meurent de faim, l'obésité fait des ravages.

Cependant, les expressions telles que "au moment où", "à l'heure où", 
gardent leur signification temporelle. Elles n'expriment l'opposition qu'en même temps que la simultanéité.

On ne dira donc pas :

> *Au moment où les chats chassent les souris, les chiens ne le font pas.

On comprendrait que les chiens chassent parfois les souris, mais pas quand les chats le font. On dira plutôt :

> Tandis/Alors que les chats chassent les souris, les chiens ne le font pas.

A ma connaissance, l'expression temporelle la plus neutre (celle qui porte le moins l'idée d'opposition) est "pendant que". 
La phrase suivante n'est pas un reproche :

> Pendant que tu fais la sieste, je vais aller faire les courses.

Celle-ci l'est probablement :

> Tandis que tu faisais la sieste, je suis allé faire les courses.

Une dernière remarque :

> ... and thought that the expression qualifies the entire sentence.

Notez que l'expression ne pouvait en aucun cas qualifier la phrase. "à l'heure où X" est un complément circonstanciel, et "où X" est une subordonnée relative ; donc il faut une proposition principale qui ne peut être que "d'autres ont l'interdiction...".
Si l'on remet la phrase dans l'ordre :

> Certains salariés ont l’interdiction de parler de leur job à l’heure où d'autres étalent leur vie professionnelle sur les réseaux sociaux.

La phrase a le même sens, mais le contraste est moins net.

Comment: Intéressant. Si j'avais eu besoin d'une locution qui sert à signifier à la fois l'idée de simultanéité temporelle et celle d'opposition, "alors que" est la première et la seule qui me serait venu à l'esprit.

Comment: Quant à "à l’heure où" versus  "alors que", qu'en est-il du côté registre, d’ailleurs ? Quelque chose à noter ?

Comment: Je dirais que "alors que" est un peu plus soutenu que "à l'heure où", mais en fait je n'en suis pas sûr. La différence principale est évidemment que "à l'heure où" précise que les deux événements se sont produits à la même heure.

Comment: Merci. Je me demande si avec « à la minute/second où », on peut insister plus sur la simultanéité que « à l’heure où », aussi subtile soit cette différence ? Mais j'y pense, il en va de même pour « the minute you do ... » versus « the second/instant you do ... » en anglais.

Answer (score 0):

*A l'heure où* reflects both chronological simultaneity and contrast here, but it is not a strict equivalent of *tandis que* - they are not always  interchangeable. *Tandis que* evolved to become usable in a context where time is absent and there is only opposition but *à l'heure où* didn't.

Correct :

> Sa voiture est bleue tandis que la mienne est blanche.

Not correct :

> Sa voiture est bleue à l'heure où la mienne est blanche.

See http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tandis B. 2.